# Displaying Results if a Condition Matches a Name

Tags: mysql

There is a table in our database that contains customer information including their first and last name. The first and last name are stored as separate fields and not together as one name. There is also a table which stores a referral field. In this field, someone can place the name of the customer that referred them to our services.

I would like to utilize a query that will take the referral field (which would contain the name of a prior customer) and match it up to the record to that prior customer.

I thought the below would work:

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID 
FROM APPLICATION_TABLE
JOIN APPU_USER ON APPU_APPLICATION_ID = APPLICATION_ID
LEFT JOIN APBD_APP_BASIC_DATA ON APBD_APPLICATION_ID = APPLICATION_ID
WHERE CONCAT(APPU_FIRST_NAME,' ',APPU_LAST_NAME) = APBD_REFERRAL_STRING;
```

What do I need to utilize to be able to do this?

Comment: And why doesn't your query work?  It would help if you provided some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

everything looks fine in your query. Is a good practice to put the table names when you use two or more tables in a query to avoid same fields conflicts, something like:

```
LEFT JOIN APBD_APP_BASIC_DATA ON APBD_APP_BASIC_DATA.APBD_APPLICATION_ID = APPLICATION_TABLE.APPLICATION_ID
```

also, take in mind than

```
CONCAT(APPU_FIRST_NAME,' ',APPU_LAST_NAME) = APBD_REFERRAL_STRING;
```

can cause problems if referral string is in format last name,first name or first name, last name, or with 2 spaces